# Have border on inside of bootstrap columns only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of four coloumns like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="skills">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">
            <i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>
            <br>
            Linux
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">
            <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
            <br>
            HTML5
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
            <br>
            Teamwork
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
            <br>
            Communication
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
#skills  #border {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

This produces:

[image: this]

However, when the screen is re-sized to 768px (xs) it looks like

[image: this].

What can I do to make it have borders only on the inside of the columns?

Comment: Ideally it will end up looking like [this](http://i.imgur.com/3Ctxhyq.png)

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xedtvb1b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to have less class names and be able to use it for more than 4 items you can use this.

```
#skills .border:not(:first-child){
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
@media (max-width: 992px){
    #skills .border:nth-child(odd){
        border-left: none;
    }
    #skills .border:nth-child(n+3){
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="skills" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border" >
        <i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>
        <br>
        Linux
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border" >
        <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
        <br>
        HTML5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
        <br>
        Teamwork
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
        <br>
        Communication
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taxellool/xedtvb1b/10/)

Comment: Works well, didn't know about `:not(:first-child)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it dynamic with less css code, try this out

```
.border{
     padding: 40px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
     border-right: 1px solid #CCC; 
}

/*xs*/
@media(max-width:767px){
  .border{
      border-right: none;
  }
}

/*sm*/
@media(max-width:991px){
  .border:nth-child(2n){
      border-right: none;
  }
}

/*md*/
@media(min-width:992px){
  .border:nth-child(4n){
      border-right: none;
  }

}
```

Check Demo Here https://jsfiddle.net/adratarek/q8kec8xb/4/

Answer (score 0):

Invalid usage of Id `#border`. *ID can not repet as per HTML rules.*

You should use class if you want to use it multiple times.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border" >
        <i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>
        <br>
        Linux
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border" >
        <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
        <br>
        HTML5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
        <br>
        Teamwork
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
        <br>
        Communication
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#skills .border {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xedtvb1b/)

**EDIT:**
According to your need (as you specified in comment).

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border-right" >
        <i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>
        <br>
        Linux
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 " >
        <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
        <br>
        HTML5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border-top border-right">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
        <br>
        Teamwork
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 border-top">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
        <br>
        Communication
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#skills  .border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#skills  .border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xedtvb1b/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my HTML and CSS to match this.

Comment: The HTML worked to begin with, the problem is on the smaller screen size getting the border to display more like [this](http://i.imgur.com/3Ctxhyq.png)

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: Edit still doesn't work, past xs size it is weird http://jsfiddle.net/xedtvb1b/5/

Comment: @ThomasCarroll There was an unwanted `border-right`. Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/xedtvb1b/6/

Comment: Fixed in my above answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fixed this with some media queries [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j10g1gdu/)

Media query is

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #skills  .border-right-md {
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
     #skills  .border-top {
       border-top: none;
    }
}
```